# Is the Russell paradox formalizable in type theories?

Tags: homotopy-theory, paradoxes, type-theory, formal-systems

Is the Russell paradox formalizable in type theories?

The paradox: There is no set of all sets that don't contain themselves. For if there is such a set, it must either contain itself or not contain itself. But both possibilities lead to the opposite. That's a contradiction.

In type theory, every object has a particular type, and operations and relations are restricted to objects having the appropriate type. This prevents the formation of ["junk theorems"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems). It seems to me that the formation of the "set of all sets that don't contain themselves" is not allowed in type theory. Is this correct? I would say 'yes', because there shouldn't be a general type "set", but for each type X another type "sets of objects from X". Hence Russell's paradox is ill-formed in type theory. Am I right?

Comment: [Type Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#1) was originally introduced by Russell in 1903 exactly in order to cope with the contradictions he found.

Comment: Obviously, this is not what I mean with type theory.

Comment: I mean something like the type theory of Martin-Löf or Homotopy type theory.

Answer (score 2):

While a naïve encoding of Russel's paradox will fail, there is a related phenomenon called [Girard's Paradox](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Burali-Forti's+paradox) which does exist, although not in a sufficiently-well stratified version of type theory.